# When i redirect success login to controller, not get a correct route in controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a next code to redirect in spring-security:

```java
public class FlowSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirect = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());

        if(roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            redirect.sendRedirect(request, response, "admin/");
        }else {
            redirect.sendRedirect(request, response, "user/");
        }

    }

}
```

In my controller to get this request is the next:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/"} ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminView(Model model)throws Exception{
        return "admin/index";
    }

}
```

when this controller send the temple response, i have of next error:

```
Estado HTTP 404 ? Not Found
Tipo Informe de estado

mensaje /admin/WEB-INF/views/admin/index.jsp

descripción El recurso requerido no está disponible.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
```

I don't know how to delete this in the begin the route /admin/ only need /WEB-INF/views/.....

------UPDATE-----
I have the view resolver like this.

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you `ViewResolver` to use different prefix you have to modify your configuration. It should look like the one below:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/"); // instead of /admin/WEB-INF/views
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in the setPrefix begin / and I had WEB-INF/views, thanks a lot...